# Checking for XML NODE null

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnode

Is there anyway to check for a null here before it reaches this part of the code?

```
tmpLabelData(0) = m_node.Item("CONTAINER_NAME").InnerText
```

Some XML has it while others do not. I cant seem to find a nice way to handle a null on these?

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If Not m_node.Item("CONTAINER_NAME") Is Nothing AndAlso _
       Len(m_node.Item("CONTAINER_NAME").InnerText) > 0 Then

   tmpLabelData(0) = m_node.Item("CONTAINER_NAME").InnerText 

End If
```