# Conditional action based on a child node existing with a attribute with a certain value

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to write some VB.NET code that will read the child node of the current node (called `WeekendMeeting`). If that child node exists and has an attribute called `Include` with a value of `true` I want to perform a action:

```
Dim nodeWeekend As XmlNode = nodeWeek.SelectSingleNode("/WeekendMeeting[@Include='true']")
If (nodeWeekend <> null) Then
    sEvent = CreateEventMWBWeekend(nodeWeekend, sEventSettings, strEventType, bCreated)
    If (bCreated) Then
        ' Add the weekend event to the Google Calendar
        If (Not AddEventToCalendar(strEventType, sEvent, sEventSettings, strCalendarID, oBatchRequest)) Then
            ' 
        End If
    End If
End If
```

It does not like the expression `null` in this `if` clause:

```
If (nodeWeekend <> null) Then
```

What is the right way to proceed with my action only when:

1. The child node `WeekendMeeting` exists
2. The `Include` attribute exists and has a value of `true`

Any advice welcomed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115273/checking-for-xml-node-null).

`if(Not nodeWeekend Is Nothing)`

That looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `IsNot`

```
If nodeWeekend IsNot Nothing Then
    'Code here'
End If
```